# Do FILE * continue to work if the fd linked to them is used for some other purpose?

Tags: c, macos, filestream, file-descriptor

I have generally worked only with file descriptors. I am not sure if a FILE * will continue to work correctly if the fd linked to it is used for someother purpose. Do FILE * and fd linked to it exist independently?

Comment: There is nothing in the C specification that links a `FILE` stream with anything related to file descriptors. File descriptors is an operating-system specific implementation of file handles, will typically be used on POSIX systems (like Linux and macOS). Windows might use a Windows-specific `HANDLE` instead. `FILE` is an abstraction, and the C specification doesn't say anything about implementation only about interface (the functions) and behavior.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, My question mainly originates seeing usage of `fileno()` to get a fd for that stream. That made me think that file streams are linked to fd somehow.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The question is tagged with macos as well as C, and it clearly is asking about features that are not part of the C standard, so the fact they are not part of the C standard is fine. Not every question is about standard C.

Comment: And that function is a POSIX specific function. See e.g. [this `fileno` reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fileno.html). And on POSIX systems, then yes file descriptors will be used to implement C `FILE` streams.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Please see its edit history.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The original question clearly asks about a feature that is not part of the C standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On POSIX systems, yes, the fd backs the `FILE*`. Closing the `FILE*` closes the fd. Interleaving use the fd and `FILE*` risks mucking up your data (the `FILE*` does user mode buffering that the fd bypasses); you'd have to either disable buffering (with `setvbuf` or the like) or make sure the `FILE*` is reliably flushed before anything writes to the fd directly. Otherwise, as long as nothing *closes* the fd, the `FILE*` should continue to work.

Answer (score 1):

> My question mainly originates seeing usage of fileno() to get a fd for that stream. That made me think that file streams are linked to fd somehow.

They are.

The functions in `<stdio.h>` are usually implemented as a wrapper around lower-level, OS-specific functions. This requires some bookkeeping. The standard's `FILE` structure needs to keep track "how the OS refers to the stream" (i.e., on POSIX systems, the file descriptor), but also any buffers associated with the stream, indexes into those buffers, whether the file needs to be removed after closing (`tmpfile()`), whether those buffers need to be `free()`d (because the library allocated them) or not (because the user allocated them and associated them with the stream through `setvbuf()`), the multibyte encoding state of the stream, and since C11, the mutex with which to lock the stream during operations to ensure thread-safety.

`fileno()` is a POSIX-specific function to *retrieve the file descriptor from the `FILE` struct*, with any access to that being without the knowledge of the standard library. Leading to the standard library functions having a *different* idea about the state of the stream than the operating system has, which might play merry hell with your program.

Don't mix POSIX and standard file access, unless you know exactly what you're doing.